# Identifying filter type from Difference Equation?

Tags: matlab, filters

So I am given a filter with the following DE:

$y(n)=0.9051y(n-1)-0.598y(n-2)+0.29y(n-3)-0.1958y(n-4)+0.414x(n)+0.862x(n-2)+0.414x(n-4)$

How can I determine what kind of filter it is?

Right away, by looking at the equation, I want to say it's an IIR filter. To double check, I took the z-transform and found its poles and zeros:

- Poles:
  0.667
  -0.003 $\pm$ 0.57j
- Zeros:
  $\pm$0.867j
  $\pm$1.154j

Since the poles are not at zero, then the filter must be IIR.

Moving onto the magnitude and phase response. Using `freqz` in MATLAB, I get the following frequency response:

[image]

and then plotting the magnitude and phase separately I get:

[image]

To me it looks like a band-stop filter from the magnitude response and the shift in phase.

Is this correct? Is there a systematic way of determining what kind of filter it is from the DE?

Thank you!

Comment: You are correct with the type of filter, but look again at the x-axis: normalized frequency ($\times\pi$ rad/sample). If that doesn't help (it should), think of what happens with the spectrum when sampling is involved.

Comment: @a concerned citizen 
Are you referring to it being IIR or being a band-stop filter, or both?
Tbh with you, the concept of normalized frequency still confuses me a bit, but what about it? In the top plot, I get that the phase response seems like it's constantly decreasing bc it represents the phase btw [0, k*pi] for k=1,2,3,... so it's being repeated for each 'tile'. But the phase response in the bottom plot shows me clearly that the phase is shifting at ~ pi/3

Comment: I was referring to the IIR type (though you didn't have to calculate the roots for that). About the spectrum, remember the [spectral folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Folding). The roots might be able to tell you what kind of filter is, though.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I calculated the roots bc I read a thread here saying that a recursive filter can also represent an FIR filter so the safest way to ensure was to find the poles, but yea probably not necessary for this one. 
Maybe my plots are confusing. I plotted them from 0 to 10*pi to see the pattern but I am just looking at the portion btw [0, pi] to analyze the magnitude and phase response. If I'm looking at the latter, it seems like a low-pass filter, but looking at the overall pattern, to me it seems like a band-stop filter.

Comment: Where is this answer? I'd like to downvote it. FIRs do not have recursion, IIRs do. You probably read that an IIR *could approximate* the response of an FIR, but recursion for FIRs is wrong. This is why I said there was no need to find the roots to find out what type of filter it is. But the placement of the roots can tell you what kind of filter it is (BTW, the polar form may come in handy here).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen downvote away but reading through it, seems like they are not wrong: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13824/type-of-filter-given-difference-equation

But anyway, I am unsure of what you're trying to point at here. I plotted the pole-zero map  and doing some reading on how to connect it to the filter type.

Comment: FIRs are filters whose output do not depend on the past samples of the output. That "case 1" the selected answer is talking about is misleading, I've added a comment. CICs are different in that they are an alternative representation of a moving average, so they use recursion *inside* -- which is nothing more than differentiator+integrator, whose roots cancel each other, leaving the FIR.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen hmm I see. Thanks for the clarification on that

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: I think the point of the OP is that you need to check for pole-zero cancellations, because if all poles are cancelled by zeros the result will be FIR even if there is recursion. One well-known example is the recursive implementation of a moving average filter. Obviously, IIR needs recursion, but recursion doesn't necessarily imply IIR.

Comment: @MattL. That's what I tried to say in my last comment: the roots of the differentiator and integrator cancel each other (be it CIC, or recursive running sum). But you're right, I shouldn't have said that the output doesn't depend on the past outputs (it contradicts the diff+int part), rather I should have let the roots part be the emphasis. Still, I think the selected answer in the linked question is misleading with its "case 1" part. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzBV0.png) is what I see.